# Does Incanter have support for sparse matrices?

Tags: clojure, matrix, sparse-matrix, incanter

Does Incanter have support for sparse matrices (multiplication, decomposition, solving)?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/incanter/browse_thread/thread/afe48488025d0b4a/6c8b85c06f08e554?#6c8b85c06f08e554), support for sparse matrices in Incanter is still a work in progress (and hasn't been discussed in awhile?).

Also, I don't see any evidence of sparse matrix support in the Incanter source code for the  [Matrix class](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/Matrix.java).  It still extends `DenseColumnDoubleMatrix2D`.